# Is my interpretation of this proof of a maximum principle for the discrete heat equation correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, heat-equation, finite-differences, maximum-principle

I am looking for help on this proof of a maximum principle for the discrete heat equation. The following is from Introduction to Partial Differential Equations (Tveito, Winther).

Consider the Heat Equation

[image]

with an explicit finite difference scheme that can be expressed as

[image]

where $t_m = m \Delta t, \ x_j = j\Delta x$, and $v(x_j,t_m)$ is an approximation to $u(x_j,t_m)$.

Define the rectangle

[image]

and the associated "lower boundary"

[image]

Let

[image]

Want to prove

[image]

Condition (6.22) is $1-2r \geq 0$

I am having some trouble understanding the proof of this theorem. It goes like this (upper bound only):

Assume $1-2r \geq 0$. Fix a time level $t_m$. Assume $v_j^m \leq V^+$ for $j = 1,\ldots,n$.

We then have

$v_j^{m+1} = rv_{j-1}^m + (1-2r)v_j^m + rv_{j+1}^m, \ j = 1,\ldots, n$.

Thus

$v_j^{m+1} \leq rV^+ + (1-2r)V^+ + rV^+ = V^+, \ j = 1,\ldots,n$.

Since this holds for any $j = 0,\ldots, n+1$, the result follows by induction on $m$.

Thought: We know that it holds for $m = 0, \ j = 1,\ldots,n$, due to the initial condition. We then assume it holds for an arbitrary $m$ and $j = 1,\ldots,n$. We then prove that it holds for $m+1$, and thus we are done, since the boundary conditions imply that it holds for $j = 0$ and $j = n+1$ as well.

Is this a correct interpretation? I am familiar with induction, but I got a little confused when we're treating both $m$ and $j$ at the same time, sort of speak.